# Change the timer interval while timer is running

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

How can I change the `Timer` interval, while the timer is currently running?

The methods I tried so far are:

```
for (Thread thread : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
        if (thread.getName().length() > 10) {
            if (thread.getName().substring(0, 11).equals("TimerActive")) {
                thread.interrupt();
                if (thread.isInterrupted())
                    Log.d("Timer interrupted");
                else
                    Log.d("Timer not interrupted");
            }
        }
}
```

where i try to find the currently active threads and stop the ones that are timers and then create another timer with the new interval. But for some reason the `interrupt()` method doesn't work, as i get the "Timer not interrupted" log. And in this case I will have two running timers at different interval.

The second method I tried was to to store the timers in an `ArrayList` and cancel and recreate them when I want to change the interval, but in this case I got an error which says that I can't access the timer as it was cancelled

Comment: you can't do that. you need to cancel you timer and reschedule it.

Comment: Ok, but how ? I even tried to convert the thread to Timer so i can use the .cancel() and .purge() methods, but it isn't allowed.

Comment: You can cancel the TimerTask.

Comment: @laune Ok, but can you please tell me how ?

Comment: to cancel a timer, first you need a timer. then, you need to call `cancel` on your timer.

Answer (score 0):

This prints "tick" every second but changes to every two seconds.

```
public class Y {
  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    Action task = new Action();
    timer.schedule( task, 2000, 1000 );
    Thread.sleep( 4000 );
    // this is where the user request a new interval, 2 sec.
    task.cancel();
    timer.schedule( new Action(), new Date(task.last + 2000), 2000 );
    Thread.sleep( 8000 );
    task.cancel();
  }
}

class Action extends TimerTask {
  private long last;
  public void run(){
    last = scheduledExecutionTime();
    System.out.println( "tick" );
  }
  public long getLast(){
    return last;
  } 
}
```

There may be some drift.

Comment: OK. I think I didn't explained well enough. Here's the whole situation. When my application starts, the timer is set to interrogate a server at a default value period, But if a user wants to change that interval, I want to cancel that Timer and make a new one with the new interval, as I understand that changing the interval value while timer is running is not possible.

Comment: I thought so, but I didn't realize you had a problem with the restart.

Comment: Thank you for your post, I'm not quite sure yet how to implement it, but I'll come back after I have tried it. Also, is it possible to convert class Y into a method ?

Comment: Well Y.main *is* a method, rename it to `x` and drop the arguments. Although I think you wouldn't find a `Y.x()` very useful. Depends on your app environment, which I don't know ;-)

Comment: Also, I noticed now you used the .schedule() method. If so, will the timer execute permanently, or just once ?

Comment: It's an interval timer - executes the task periodically. As you wrote in your comment. Also, just look up the javadoc.

Comment: regarding the schedule method, you could simply consider reading the doc.